# Anorm macro to generate inserter/updater?

Tags: scala, anorm

Scala Anorm 2.5.0 can generate parsers with the `Macro.namedParser`. For instance:

```
import anorm.{ Macro, RowParser }
case class Info(name: String, year: Option[Int])
val parser: RowParser[Info] = Macro.namedParser[Info]
// Generated as: get[String]("name") ~ get[Option[Int]]("year") map { case name ~ year => Info(name, year) }

val result: List[Info] = SQL"SELECT * FROM list".as(parser.*)
```

Is there a macro to get the other way around, that is, to insert/update?
something like:

```
val myInfo = Info("John", 1950)
val mapper = Macro.mappings[Info]
SQL("insert into list (name, year) values ({name}, {year})")
  .on(mapper(myInfo)).executeInsert()
```

Which would generate:

```
SQL("insert into list (name, year) values ({name}, {year})")
  .on('name -> myInfo.name, 'country -> myInfo.name).executeInsert()
```

https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAnorm

Comment: Anorm doesn't provide automatic update, as it's focused result parsing. It probably won't.